# Time of extracted frame from video using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp

I'm using the command 

`ffmpeg -i video.webm -vf fps=1 thumb%04d.jpg`

to get one frame every second. However, I cannot figure out way to get the exact timestamp of an extracted frame. I need that timestamp for processing.

Can you please help?

Thanks so much,
Vu

Comment: If you set `fps=1`, the timecode will be 0, 1, 2, etc., no?

Comment: No it does not correct. See https://superuser.com/questions/575854/can-ffmpeg-extract-images-from-a-video-with-timestamps. Also, we tested many times and it did not necessarily to get first frame of a second.

Comment: Well, you could use a `"fps=1,drawtext=timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':r=1"` filter and see what is rendered in the output images. Or just as shown in the other post, use `text='%{pts\:hms}'`.

Comment: Thanks. This post is very close to what I want https://superuser.com/questions/994870/how-to-add-the-timestamp-as-a-part-of-the-generated-image-file-name-in-ffmpeg, but it seems not completely work.

Comment: That won't work, as ffmpeg cannot dynamically set the output file name.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://superuser.com/questions/841872/how-do-i-extract-the-timestamps-associated-with-frames-ffmpeg-extracts-from-a-vi